# scroll down when click on down fadeInUp wow type class in wordpress using a jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

```html
<a href="#" id="down" class="down fadeInUp wow ">
                        <span class="mouse"><span></span></span>
                        <small> scroll down </small>
                    </a>

 1. List item
```

above is a html and when click on fadeINup than it scroll down.

Comment: and the reason we lost 5 seconds of our life is ?

Comment: reason is does't work the scroll down in page.

Comment: you don't have any js script to trigger the scroll

Comment: var body = $('down, body');

    $('.toTop').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        body.animate({scrollTop:0}, '500', 'swing');

}); use that script

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: ok, i find my mistake.thanks for help me